# Creating a Google Analytics view that ONLY shows subdomain traffic?

Tags: google-analytics

We have one GA snippet shared across two websites: our primary domain (oursite.com) and a subdomain (sub.oursite.com).  How would I go about creating a view solely to analyze traffic on the subdomain?

It's probably easy, but I can't seem to dial in the correct filter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create a new view and add to it a new filter that includes traffic from hostname (entering the hostname you want).

- create new filter
- filter name: my host sub.oursite.com
- filter type: custom
- include
- filter field: hostname
- filter pattern: sub.oursite.com